# Mark the job in Laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

How can I mark the job in Laravel 5.5 to find it further?

For example: user1 can create 5 jobs by click on button.

For some reason, he need to delete some jobs.

I know that I can mark the queue by `->onQueue('queue_user1')`, but in that case command `php artisan queue:work` will not work, because we need to specify the queue name.

`dispatch()` function doesn't return job id too